# How to address the position number of a vector in a loop using R?

Tags: r

Possibly, this is terrible easy, but I am at a loss right now. I want to address the position number of vector which I am looping over. Here is a very reduced example, of course the  function(s) I would like to loop over is much more complex than `print`. Instead of "test_abc", I would like to get "test_1" and so forth.

```
strvec <- c("abc", "def", "ghi")
for (i in strvec) {
     print(paste("test_", i, sep=""))
     print(paste("test_", i[i], sep=""))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strvec <- c("abc", "def", "ghi")
for (i in seq_along(strvec)) {
  print(paste("test_", i, sep=""))
  print(paste("test_", strvec[i], sep=""))
}

#[1] "test_1"
#[1] "test_abc"
#[1] "test_2"
#[1] "test_def"
#[1] "test_3"
#[1] "test_ghi"
```

However, there is a very good chance that there are much better (and probably faster) alternatives to a `for` loop to reach your final goal.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I realise that `for` is not as fast as `apply` but in my case `for` comes in more handy.

Comment: @non-numeric_argument I doubt that it is more handy than `lapply`/`sapply`, but if you are happy with `for`...

Answer (score 1):

what about looping over `1:length(strvec)`?

Comment: Thank you for yor fast help!